# how to add notifications to my website for each user

Tags: php, facebook

I have one site where I need to use Facebook a notification that I had  implemented. But the problem is that when user clicks on the notification then he redirecting to a canvas page which I don't have. How to redirect it to my web page, and is this legal from Facebook?

I added the page name 'login.php' of my website page but it's showing inside canvas page.

```
$params = array( 'access_token' => $accessToken, 'href' => 'login.php', 'template' => $notification_message['FB']['message'], );
$facebook->api('/' . $userId . '/notifications/', 'post', $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a canvas app for redirecting via JavaScript – but that would be in violation of the [Platform Polices](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), which explicitly state:

> Policies, I. Features and Functionality, Point 11)
>
> The primary purpose of your Canvas or Page Tab app on Facebook must not be to simply redirect users out of the Facebook experience and onto an external site.